# Groovy variable double substitution

Tags: grails, groovy, groovyshell, groovy-console

I would like to perform **double substitution**.

When printing:

```
def y    = "\${x}"
def x    = "world"
def z    = "Hello ${y}"
println z
```

It prints:

```
Hello ${x}
```

When I would like it to print `Hello World`, I tried performing a double evaluation `${${}}`, casting it to `org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl`, and a desperate `${y.toStrin()`}

**Edit:**

To be more clear I mean this, but in Groovy:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68042/double-and-triple-substitution-in-bash-and-zsh
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68035/foo-and-zsh

(**Why I am doing this?**: Because we have some text files that we need evaluate with groovy variables; the variables are many and in different part of the code are different, therefore I would like to have a solution working across all cases, not to have to bind each time each variable, not adding many lines of code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So with what you have you're escaping the $ so it is just interpreted as a string.

For what you are looking to do I would look into Groovys's templating engines:
http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/template-engines.html

After reading your comment I played around with a few ideas and came up with this contrived answer, which is also probably not quite what you are looking for:

```
import groovy.lang.GroovyShell

class test{
    String x = "world"
    String y = "\${x}"
    void function(){
        GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell();
        Closure c = shell.evaluate("""{->"Hello $y"}""")
        c.delegate = this
        c.resolveStrategry = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
        String z = c.call()
        println z
    }
}

new test().function()
```

But it was the closest thing I could come up with, and may lead you to something...

Comment: If I am not wrong this would push me to use bindings, that is not what I am looking for since I would need a lot of code for each case. I was looking for a solution as easy as ${${text}}

Comment: I updated my answer with another idea, although it is a bit contrived

Comment: Thanks I tried it out and it was what I was looking for. It does double (and triple) substitution, and it can be used as standalone function passing y as parameter!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right, you are reading `y` from somewhere else.  So you want to evaluate `y` as a GString after `y` and then `x` have been loaded.  `groovy.util.Eval` will do this for simple cases.  In this case, you have just one binding variable: `x`.

```
def y = '${x}'
def x = 'world'

def script = "Hello ${y}"
def z = Eval.me('x', x, '"' + script + '".toString()') // create a new GString expression from the string value of "script" and evaluate it to interpolate the value of "x"
println z
```

Comment: This would be simple substitution, not double substitution!

Comment: This prints "Hello world".  Is that not the result you are after?

Comment: Also `println "Hello world"` does, but I was not looking for this kind of solution. I was interested in a way to implement double substitution, something like this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68042/double-and-triple-substitution-in-bash-and-zsh, I will update the question :)

Comment: If your intent is to load the contents of `y` from somewhere else, then you want it's text to be treated as a GString, I think Eval will do that.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out!